# Avoiding reaching memory limits while making a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, memory

This is Problem 1352C over at Codeforces and I'm using Python 3.x to solve it, so memory is a concern.

```
finl = []
for i in range(n):
    div, no = map(int, input().split())
    lis = [j for j in range(no*div) if j%div != 0]

    finl.append(str(lis[no-1]))
print("\n".join(finl))
```

This is my code so far. I take each case, and make a list with all the numbers not divisible by the number in question, `div` here, and `no` is the nth number which is the necessary output. This is a simplistic approach, and understandably, I am reaching the memory limit in just the first set of numbers.

My question here is: how can I forego making a whole list (and thus wasting memory) and just save the output that I need (the `no`th entry) to the `finl` list (the list of outputs I made that gets printed in the end)? I want to stick with this approach for now, and I couldn't find something similar that's been answered (without looking at the problem's solutions and thus skipping part of the problem-solving process)

Comment: You don't need to store all the `j`s in `lis` that preced the k-th `j` your interested in.

Comment: @MilanCermak yes yes, I don't exactly know how I could do that. Not very new to py yet still, sorry! If you can suggest a way, then I'd be very grateful

Comment: Instead of accumulating all the values in the `lis`, add another for loop until you find the element you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the entire list upfront then taking the slice, create the generator and pull out the items using `next` for given `no`:

```py
for i in range(n):
    div, no = map(int, input().split())
    gen = (j for j in range(no*div) if j%div != 0)
    lis = [next(gen) for _ in range(no)]
    finl.append(str(lis))
```

**PS:** It may throw `StopIterationError` if `no` is greater that the number of items the generator can `yield`, you may want to handle it if that's the case.

Comment: Ah, this returns nothing but a list of 1's. I'll try to work this out with your suggested approach, though

Comment: okay, my bad. it is recreating the generator again, just store it locally before using it. Check the updated answer once.